# JSF2 : inject service objects to managedbean from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have tested this, trying to inject an service object to a @ManagedBean, but it failed with a nullpointerexception, being the userService is null.

I am currently using Tomcat 7, JSF 2, and here are some of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.hibernate-version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    ....
</properties>
```

Here is the exception trace :

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.albertkam.ui.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 23 more
```

Here's my ManagedBean :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
    private MstUser entityMstUser;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.entityMstUser = new MstUser();
    }
```

And here's my service bean ..

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    public void login(MstUser entityMstUser) {
```

And here's my applicationContext.xml ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.albertkam" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>albert simpleWebapp</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/datasourceContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

And my faces-config.xml, although there's really nothing related in here ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>in</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>org.albertkam.common.messages</base-name>
         <var>msgs</var>
      </resource-bundle>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>org.albertkam.common.errors</base-name>
         <var>errs</var>
      </resource-bundle>

      <!-- <message-bundle>id.co.sofcograha.override_messages</message-bundle>  -->
    </application>

    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.albertkam.common.BusinessExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
</faces-config>
```

I wonder if it's possible to do such thing, injecting a Spring managed bean to a @ManagedBean ?

Please share your experience in this ..

Thank you !

*********** added some new experiment results ****************

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>Hello,
```

I have tested this, trying to inject an service object to a @ManagedBean, but it failed with a nullpointerexception, being the userService is null.

I am currently using Tomcat 7, JSF 2, and here are some of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.hibernate-version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    ....
</properties>
```

Here is the exception trace :

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.albertkam.ui.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 23 more
```

Here's my ManagedBean :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
    private MstUser entityMstUser;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.entityMstUser = new MstUser();
    }
```

And here's my service bean ..

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    public void login(MstUser entityMstUser) {
```

And here's my applicationContext.xml ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.albertkam" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>albert simpleWebapp</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/datasourceContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

And my faces-config.xml, although there's really nothing related in here ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>in</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>org.albertkam.common.messages</base-name>
         <var>msgs</var>
      </resource-bundle>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>org.albertkam.common.errors</base-name>
         <var>errs</var>
      </resource-bundle>

      <!-- <message-bundle>id.co.sofcograha.override_messages</message-bundle>  -->
    </application>

    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.albertkam.common.BusinessExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
</faces-config>
```

I wonder if it's possible to do such thing, injecting a Spring managed bean to a @ManagedBean ?

Please share your experience in this ..

Thank you !

*********** added some new experiment results ****************

Just now i tried using @Named to replace @ManagedBean and @Inject to replace @Autowired, and it worked, although i still dont really understand the reason why.

So here's the modifed managed bean :

```
@Named("userBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
    private MstUser entityMstUser;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.entityMstUser = new MstUser();
    }
```

This works, the service object got injected, although the userService is managed by Spring ? How is that possible ?

Here's some additional things that i add along the way ..

I added this in the web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I also added an empty WEB-INF/beans.xml

And this inside the faces-config.xml
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver

Im a bit concerned here with using the @Named, because i've had a [bad experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524280/jsf-2-viewscoped-problem-bean-not-persisted-when-redisplaying-the-same-page) using it along with ViewScoped. I'd feel alot safer when i have @ManagedBean being able to be injected with service objects by the spring framework.

I wonder what you guys usually do to connect the ManagedBean with your business service objects .. using CDI, or pure Spring, or the combination of them ?

Answer (score 5):

missing variable resolver in `faces-config.xml`

```
<application>  
  <variable-resolver>  
    org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver 
  </variable-resolver>  
 </application>
```

missing RequestContextListener listener in `web.xml`

```
<listener> 
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>  
</listener>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick response. I've added some details in the original post. Correct me if im wrong, but DelegatingVariableResolver is so that i can #{springBeanName}, and RequestContextListener is so that i dont need to use @ManagedBean anymore, and instead i could just define the bean in the spring xml or use the @Component on the bean, avoiding 2 different containers (jsf and spring) taking care of a bean. But i prefer to have the the @ManagedBean to be handled by JSF, and have Spring inject a service bean to the ManagedBean. I tried adding those you mentioned, but still failed.

Comment: I don't see variable resolver in `faces-config.xml` it is used to resolve any dependency you inject. so that your jsf container will do lookup over spring's context if it doesn't find in jsf's context

Comment: Ah sorry, i forgot to mention that i added this also @ the faces-config.xml : <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver> .. i found out that this is for the jsf 1.2 and above. With the 2 additions you suggested, i couldnt get the @ManagedBean to work, which will be a very good solution for me. I want to avoid @Named as it conflicts with the @ViewScoped i want to use heavily in many places. Could you please shed me some more lights on this ? Im quite confused why using @Named works, but not @ManagedBean.And what do you usually use for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

In your applications context xml define a bean for "UserService" for example,

```
<bean id="userService" class="org.albertkam.yourclassname"/>
```