# @Autowire in Spring

Tags: spring, autowired

I am trying to understand how to use Authowire in Spring.

I saw a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724412/jsf2-inject-service-objects-to-managedbean-from-spring) and understood how to use it.

However, isn't spring working on interfaces?

Isn't the UserService needs to be an interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't *have* to use interfaces but it will make you life more simple at some point in the future.

Alas, as with all predictions of the future, this assumption could be wrong. In that case, the effort to create and maintain an interface would be wasted.

Moreover, modern IDEs offer powerful refactorings to replace a specific type with an interface.

Comment: So do you recommend to get read of interfaces if I know for sure that there will be one class that implements them?

Comment: @Odelya: You would need interfaces for the cases when Spring generates a proxy for your class. For example, if you have a service and use AOP features of Spring to introduce transactions, you need an interface for your service class, otherwise you will get a class cast exception.

Comment: Not necessarily. Spring can create CGlib proxies for any non-final class with an empty constructor. Spring+AspectJ doesn't even have that limitation.

Comment: I use transactions annotation. @Ophir - do you mean that I don't need to use interface if I am using transactions?

Comment: @Odelya: As I said: You don't have to use an interface. It will just make things more simple to replace one implementation with another **if you need it**. If you don't need it, interfaces have no advantage except to get you in a mindset to separate API from implementation.