# Trouble spring injection in JSF2 Bean with annotation

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I have a trouble with Spring Injection in my web project. I must use in a JSF2 bean.

Show my work :

**SgbdServiceImpl.java** (shorted)

```
@Service
public class SgbdServiceImpl implements SgbdService {


    @Override
    public List<Sgbd> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Sgbd findOneByName(String nom) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**SgbdBean**

```
@Component
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="sgbd")
public class SgbdBean {

    @Autowired
    SgbdService sgbdService;

    public List<Sgbd> findAll(){
        return sgbdService.findAll();
    }

}
```

I put this configuration in the file : **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This Spring configuration in **applicationContext.xml** :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.erdf.agir.services" />

</beans>
```

And, in **faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

I would like call findAll() from service but i obtain all time nullPointerException from sgbdService attribut (Autowired failled ?)

I follow this example : http://rsuna.blogspot.fr/2013/05/how-to-integrate-jsf-20-with-spring-3.html

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF2 : inject service objects to managedbean from Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724412/jsf2-inject-service-objects-to-managedbean-from-spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a context clash; using both `@Component` and `@ManagedBean` on the same class definition put your bean in two contexts: JSF and Spring's. Let's now establish that `@Autowired` will not work in the JSF context.

1. You could get rid of the spring-based annotations and go with a JSF-centric setup. What this will leave with you with

   ```
   @SessionScoped
   @ManagedBean(name="sgbd")
   public class SgbdBean {

   @ManagedProperty(value="#{sgbdServiceImpl}")
   SgbdService sgbdService;

   public List<Sgbd> findAll(){
       return sgbdService.findAll();
   }
   ```

   }
2. You could stick with a strictly spring-centric approach with

   ```
   @Component
   public class SgbdBean {

   @Autowired
   SgbdService sgbdService;

       public List<Sgbd> findAll(){
           return sgbdService.findAll();
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it works better. I see a another mistake in : <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>. It's not /WEB-INF but directly WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

Things I have encountered

1) Better to mention service name with annotation - **@Service("sgbdService")**

2) Rather than @ManagedBean it is better to use @Qualifier annotation - 
   **@Qualifier("sgbdBean")**

3) Add `<context:sping-configured/>` entry to applicationContext.xml file

4) Try with top level component scan entry as 
`<context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.erdf" />`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.1) I use name for my services. 2) I use Qualifier but in the view file (Xhtml) doesn't occur to get the bean.  3) Why use a AOP configuration ?  4) It's done.