# JSF 2.0 managedbeans problem!

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

ı have a problem about `jsf 2.0` managedbeans. the problem is that, ı create two objects in my managedbean and when ı set the data of one of them the other changes. the following code show the problem,

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mainn")

@ViewScoped

public class Mainn {

 private  AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket one = new AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket();

 private  AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket two = new AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket();

    public void Hesapla() {

          one.setX2(5); 

          System.out.println(two.getX2()); // printf 5 the value of "one" 

       }

}
```

How can ı solve it ?

Comment: you shouldn't use `new` for managed properties, and as you are getting `two.getX2()` you might have default value of `x2` as `5`

Comment: no, there is no any default value for x2. which value ı set for 'one' ı get the same value for 'two'.

Comment: is this the complete code or you have trimmed out some thing from this class ?

Comment: Is your `x2` member declared static in `AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `x2` member **not** as `static` in `AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket`.

Comment: the problem is resolved with not using static in AyniAndaDoğrusalIkiliHareket. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

[JSF 2 : ViewScoped Problem, bean not persisted when redisplaying the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524280/jsf-2-viewscoped-problem-bean-not-persisted-when-redisplaying-the-same-page)

maybe that post same as with your problem.